# Retrieve typing.List[X] type

Tags: python, type-hinting

For the following typing:

```
import typing
foo: typing.List[int] = []
```

How to retrieve type of items in foo list (through type hinting)  ? Result must be `<class 'int'>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are looking for something like this.

```
import sys
import typing

foo: typing.List[int] = []
foo_one: typing.Tuple[float] = ()

def _get_type_of_item(param):
    """
    typing.get_type_hints(obj[, globals[, locals]]):

    Return a dictionary containing type hints for a function, method, module or class object.
    """
    return typing.get_type_hints(sys.modules[__name__])[param].__args__


print(_get_type_of_item('foo')) # this will print (<class 'int'>,)
print(_get_type_of_item('foo_one')) # this will print (<class 'float'>,)
```